# to implement online converting engine from browser to web server

Tags: architecture, client-server

im looking for common way to build the right client server architecture 
when my goal is :
the browser submit data to the web server -> 
the web server response with converted pdf file based on that data 
now my question is this :
where to implement this convention engine ( that is static lib ) 
as web server plug in (apache, lighthttpd,nginx)?
or as separate process in different server ?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me like you are wanting to dynamically generate PDFs based on the data captured from a web-based form? If so, there are many different ways to achieve this- and each person from each language discipline will promote their method as being simple.